# QField auto-numbering

Tags: qfield, default, integer, numbering

A simple need but no success in default auto-numbering an integer type field in QField.  Have tried $id, $row_number, etc., but no default value is entered on point digitization. An expression such as maximum("id") + 1 requires "*apply default value on update*" which appears to sometimes overwrite values on synchronization in QGIS - which is detrimental to 'permanently' indexing points in the data-collection/synchronization process. Have searched these posting and other on-line sources and tried all options found.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> An expression such as maximum("id") + 1 requires "apply default value
> on update"

Although there is a caution that states:

> *"Using fields in a default value expression only works if 'Apply default value on update' is checked"*

...this is NOT the case. I number sequentially across 3 layers (a point layer, a line layer and a polygon layer, with the following expression, and 'Apply default value on update' is NOT checked and it works.

```
Max(
    aggregate('tree_pt','max', "num"), 
    aggregate('tree_ln','max', num"), 
    aggregate('tree_ar','max', "num"),
    0)
+1
```

I use the Max() funtion with an argument = 0 to account for an empty dataset.

But, if you are using this sequence as a primary key in a multi-user environment, or will upload the data to a database elsewhere, you may wish to consider using a uuid; Set default = uuid().